# Not able to execute linux command using processBuilder

Tags: java, linux

I using Processbuilder as follows:

```
            List<String> args = initArgs();
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(args);
            tdmServerProcess = pb.start();

            handleInfoLog(tdmServerProcess.getInputStream());
            handleErrorLog(tdmServerProcess.getErrorStream());
```

In the `initArgs` method I am setting the linux commands I want to execute, as follows:

```
args.add("java -version");
args.add(javaHome + File.separator + "bin" + File.separator + "java");
```

first command is getting executed successfully. But second is failing with following error:

> /opt/java7/bin/java: cannot execute binary file

though i have execute permission, following are permission bits:

```
-r-xr-xr-x
```

I am able to execute the same command from terminal.

Answer (score 2):

The error "cannot execute binary file" means that the java file is not valid.
Maybe the 'java -version' is actually running java from another location in your path, and the /opt/java7/bin/java is not valid. Try running the '/opt/java7/bin/java' manually, and check the result.
Check also the location of java in your path by running `which java` using the same user that your are running your java code with.

Comment: I am able to execute following command -bash-4.2$ /opt/java7/bin/java -version
java version "1.7.0.09"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0.09-jinteg_2014_02_03_13_09-b00)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03-jre1.7.0.09-rc1, mixed mode)

Comment: Then your code is running in a 32bit JVM. _cannot execute binary file_ is usually caused for trying to run wrong binnaries for your arch. Just try `which java` to see what JVM are you really running.

Comment: which java gives me following: -bash-4.2$ which java
/opt/java7/bin/java

Answer (score 0):

You apparently are trying to execute two separate commands, first "java -version" and then "/opt/java7/bin/java" ?

That's not how it works. Rather, all of the arguments are appended and one process is started. In your case, the command is "java -version /opt/java7/bin/java"

Try running that at the console - I'm betting that you get the same error.

Comment: you are rite. its getting executed as java -version /opt/java7/bin/java. I tried the same on console. following is the output: -bash-4.2$ java -version /opt/java7/bin/java
java version "1.7.0.09"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0.09-jinteg_2014_02_03_13_09-b00)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03-jre1.7.0.09-rc1, mixed mode)